# Dubai Duty Free for One hour layover

Tags: layovers, short-connections, dxb, duty-free

I have 1 hour and 15 mins layover at DXB Dubai Airport will it be enough to buy a watch at Dubai Duty free? (I have same terminal [TERMINAL 3] to board in and out)

Comment: Which terminal?  I commuted long distance through dbx a lot.  Really, I'd say the answer is NO, basically.  It just depends on your gate.  If you get unlucky and get stuck on a bus-gate :/ there's no chance.

Comment: BTW As bad says the prices are horrible there.  Buy watches in HK.

Comment: @Fattie Terminal 3

Comment: it's huge and you're very unlikely to have time.  just go to your new gate.  it MIGHT BE that the watch shop you have in mind is right by the new gate, if so fine.  But I'd go straight to the new gate first.  good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your flights run to schedule then probably just about but it will be a bit tight.  It is a well managed and efficient airport but very large, your arrival and departure gate may be far apart.  I'd suggest that when you arrive, carefully check your gate for the next flight and ensure that you allow enough time to get there.

Also, I would not assume that the prices are good.  Research the items that you are considering and prices available elsewhere e.g. online.